# Magento2 How to create custom variables to use on config.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration, custom-variable

In the etc/config.xml I can use some variables, like {{base_url}}, but I need to use other urls in this config.

How I can create custom variables to use in the etc/config.xml file?

Example:

In my config.xml I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <payment>
        <pagseguro>
            <application_authorization_redirect>{{base_url}}pagseguro/application/authorization</application_authorization_redirect>
            <after_authorization_redirect>http://frontendapp.com/pagseguro</after_authorization_redirect>
        </pagseguro>
    <payment>
</config>
```

In the "application_authorization_redirect" I used the variable {{base_url}} but in the "after_authorization_redirect" I hardcoded the url, but I what to use here a dynamic url too. Something like:

```
<after_authorization_redirect>{{frontendapp_url}}pagseguro</after_authorization_redirect>
```

Comment: Actually, your question is not clear to me. Could you give an example?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thanks for the reply. I edited my post with an example.